# How to test if ancestor's __init__ was called with correct arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm writing unit test for class B, which should check that when I create B() - correct call of `super().__init__` was executed.
I'm using this code:

```
import pytest

class A:
  def __init__(self, some_val, **kwargs):
    self.some_val = some_val


class B(A):
  def __init__(self, some_val, some_other_val, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(some_val, **kwargs)
    self.some_other_val = some_other_val


def test_example(mocker):
  def side_effect(self, some_val, **kwargs):
    original_init(self, some_val, **kwargs)

  original_init = A.__init__

  mocker.patch.object(A, "__init__", side_effect=side_effect)

  some_val = "abc"
  some_other_val = "xyz"

  instance = B(some_val, some_other_val)

  A.__init__.assert_called_once_with(instance, some_val)
```

But getting this error

```
TypeError: test_example.<locals>.side_effect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'some_val'
```

Comment: Why not just test that its some_val attribute is set? That's the behaviour you want, independent of the implementation details.

Comment: It could be A.__ some_val, so I will need to write <assert B()._A__some_val == some_val>, which doesn't look pretty. Also, it could be even some other logic in class A \__init__ which uses <some_val>, and the logic could change overtime.

Comment: It's not name-mangled in what you've shown. If it was the whole point would be to keep that from child classes, entirely internal to A, so it wouldn't be an appropriate thing to test directly.

Comment: In general, unit tests should test the results, not the implementation.

Comment: "which should check that when I create B() - correct call of super().__init__ was executed." In your own words, **why should it matter** whether that happened? **Exactly what, concretely, will go wrong** if it didn't happen? Test for **that**.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to your question without the use of `pytest` because in general I use only the Python module `unittest`.

I haven't changed anything in your classes A and B, but I have modified your test code. In the code I have added some comments.

```
#import pytest      # <--- Removed this import
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class A:
  def __init__(self, some_val, **kwargs):
    self.some_val = some_val


class B(A):
  def __init__(self, some_val, some_other_val, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(some_val, **kwargs)
    self.some_other_val = some_other_val

# I have created this test class by unittest
class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    #def test_example(mocker):     # <--- Your definition of test_example
    def test_example(self):

        #def side_effect(self, some_val, **kwargs):     # <--- This is your side_effect() function
        #    original_init(self, some_val, **kwargs)    # <--- This is your side_effect() function

        def side_effect(some_val, **kwargs):    # <--- New side_effect() function
            observed.append(some_val)
            original_init(A, some_val, **kwargs)

        original_init = A.__init__

        observed = []         # <--- I have added this list for test

        #mocker.patch.object(A, "__init__", side_effect=side_effect) <--- substitute with the following context manager
        with mock.patch.object(A, "__init__", side_effect=side_effect): # <--- I have introduced this context manager
            some_val = "abc"
            some_other_val = "xyz"

            instance = B(some_val, some_other_val)

            #A.__init__.assert_called_once_with(instance, some_val)         # your TEST
            self.assertEqual(["abc"], observed)               # My TEST

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The idea is the execution of the following check:

```
self.assertEqual(["abc"], observed)
```

The previous test defines the expected list `["abc"]` which contains the string `abc` that is the value of the variable `some_val` passed to the instantiation `B(some_val, some_other_val)`.

The test checks if the instruction `B(some_val, some_other_val)` causes the adding of the value of `some_val` to the list `observed`.
This adding is executed by the function `side_effect()` with the instruction:

```
observed.append(some_val)
```

So if in the list `observed` is present the string `abc` means that:

> the **ancestor's** `A.__init__()` method is called by the `B.__init__()` method (`__init__` method of the subclass).

Comment: @archjkeee Could you give a feedback to my answer please?